# How to Remove "Powered by Jekyll with Chirpy theme."

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I want to remove the "Powered by Jekyll with Chirpy theme." appearing at the footer of every page with other customized messages.

It works when I run `bundle exec jekyll s` locally and I remove the following from the file under `C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-theme-chirpy-5.1.0/\_includes/footer.html`.

```
    <div class="footer-right">
      <p class="mb-0">
        {% capture _platform %}
          <a href="https://jekyllrb.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Jekyll</a>
        {% endcapture %}

        {% capture _theme %}
          <a href="https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Chirpy</a>
        {% endcapture %}

        {{ site.data.locales[lang].meta
          | default: 'Powered by :PLATFORM with :THEME theme.'
          | replace: ':PLATFORM', _platform | replace: ':THEME', _theme
        }}

      </p>
    </div>
```

However, it still shows on my Github page.
PS: AFAIK we can remove the "Powered by .." under the license.

Comment: Seems correct. The meta information from the yaml files comes from https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy/blob/3969b28743392bb47de2365651df0e9b11d50c71/_includes/footer.html, can you share a GitHub repository URL?

Comment: Hi. All github.io page are similar with the footer that includes "Powered by ..." in every page.

https://datamleng.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite the original theme's footer file, change the `_includes/footer.html` file and create the folder and file in your repository. The GitHub pages deployment will use this file and overwrite the theme's footer.

Have a look at [this docs.github.com page](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll#customizing-your-themes-html-layout) to see how to change the layout. Adjusting the footer works the same.

Regarding the license, the theme's MIT license contains:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
> all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

I guess [it's not ok to remove the copyright completely](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180784/is-it-okay-to-remove-copyright-info-from-a-free-open-source-api-even-if-you-are). You can remove it from the footer but you should keep it somewhere.

Comment: Depends what is meant by "in ... the Software". Your local fork of the chirpy repo might still include the copyright notice, which would have to stay there if you distributed the software. I'm not sure that it follows that the notice must be displayed as a UI element on the website produced as an output of the software.

Answer (score 1):

The meta information is coming from the files under the (language) locales. For my site I have edited only the en.yml file see the attached image. You can modify the whole of the files under locale. The param value is coming from the _config.yml file.

#meta: Powered by :PLATFORM and with :THEME theme.

meta: Powered by Open Source CMS.

[en.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDSWS.png)